# monte carlo simulation, matlab, normal distribution

Tags: matlab, simulink

My question is about the evaluation of Monte Carlo simulation results. I have a model in Simulink and I simulate the model with different deviation of parameters.

I have collected the results of 100 simulations, which are normally distributed and I use mean and standard deviation of resulted output when enough repetition is reached. Up to this point, there is no problem.

But since the variables are random, in some cases there are some parameters that are too low or too high, which results in Inf or NaN value as the output. I want to find out a way to represent those infinite results without disturbing or missing any result of the outputs.

Any idea will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure there's no defect in your simulations?

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting Inf or NaN in your simulations, then the chances are that there is a defect in your simulation, or you should be rejecting those results. If you have Inf values, then your mean and standard deviation ought to be Inf also.

You can use the `isfinite` function to detect non-finite results. These can either be removed, or replaced with new simulation results.

Comment: inf or NaN results is unavoidable because in some cases whenever I have negative voltages I terminate the simulation as in actual case it's not possible to operate at such voltage level. Also due to nature of MonteCarlo Simulation I generate parameters randomly with specified mean and std but in some cases even the generated values have wanted mean and std a few of them may be too small/big which results negative voltage and termination of simulation, so when some results of monte carlo are not usable what is the best way to conclude on results,omit results and increase number of simulation?

Answer (score 0):

There are some solutions on the file exchange that may help.

This [submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15776-ignore-nan) will not use NaN values in your calculations